# Shell script to run a process in background parse its output and start service if the previous process contains a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

I need to write a shell script that starts a process in background and parse its output till it checks the output doesn't contains any Error in its output. The process will keep on running in the background as it needs to listen on ports. If the process output contained an error exit the script.

Based on the output of the previous process (it didn't contain any errors, the process was able to establish connection to DB) run the next command.

I have tried many approches suggested on Stack overflow, which includes:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/best-way-to-follow-a-log-and-execute-a-command-when-some-text-appears-in-the-log
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45941/tail-f-until-text-is-seen
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137030/how-do-i-extract-the-content-of-quoted-strings-from-the-output-of-a-command

```sh
/home/build/a_process 2>&1 | tee "output_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").log"
tail -fn0 "output_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").log" | \
while read line ; do
if [ echo "$line" | grep "Listening" ]
then
/home/build/b_process 2>&1 | tee "output_script_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").log"
elif [ echo "$line" | grep "error occurred in load configuration" ] || [ echo "$line" | grep "Binding Failure" ]
then
sl -e
fi
done
```

The problem is since the process keep running despite it contains the text i was searching for it gets stuck in parsing the staring and never able to exit watching the output or tailing. As a result it's not able to execute next command.

Comment: The `a_process` is something you want to monitor? Why `b_process` is here and what does it do? You need to run something in the background with `&`. Or remove the `tail -fn0` and just connect `tee` output to `while read line` input. `if [ echo "$line" | grep "Listening" ]; then` is very invalid. It's just `if <<<"line" grep -q "Listening"; then` without `[` `]`.

Comment: Yes a_process is the one i want to monitor and the b_process depends on a. b_process should not start if a_process has returned an error

Answer (score 0):

On surface, the issue is with "tee" command (a_process ... | tee).

Recall that a pipeline will result in the shell

1. Creating the pipeline between the command
2. Waiting for the LAST command the finish.

Since the tee will not finish until a_process is done, and since a_process is a daemon, your script may wait forever (at least, until a_process exit).

In this case, consider sending the whole pipeline to the background.

```
log_file=output_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").log
( /home/build/a_process 2>&1 | tee "$logfile" ) &
tail -fn0 "$logfile" | 
...
```

Side note: consider setting the log file into a variable. This will make it easier to maintain (and understand) the script.